# Excel VBA - Filter Data then remove filter, keeping the filtered data hidden

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a report with multiple columns. I need to hide rows where all columns have $0. Using VBA, I added a last column that equals zero if all the prior columns are zero. I then run an autofilter on that last column to hide the columns that should be hidden. I would then like to delete the last column, but keep the hidden rows hidden. However, if I delete the column, the filter gets undone. I remember years ago I had a way to keep the filter after deleting the filtering column, but I can't recall how I did it.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can make the opposite filtering, hide manually all rows, then remove filter...(I wonder what's gonna happen)

Comment: Insert of filter set row height to 0? (you're already in VBA...) (or actually delete the rows...)

Comment: The reason I want to use a filter is because when you manually hide rows it can take a few seconds, while filtering works in milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the **Advanced Filter** feature, on the Data tab.

[image]

You can either filter the list in place (without the filter-arrows) or to another location in the same worksheet. **Added** (thanks to pnuts) the List Range in the screen shot should be A5:L107.

If the values are strings then the criteria in the COUNTIF would be "$0", but I hope that they are numbers.

The number 12 is the number of columns I have in my example table.

Record the steps if you want to use them in some VBA code.

Comment: @pnuts +1 Good spot, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do:

```
Dim StartCell As Range, CurrentCell As Range
Set StartCell = Range("G2") 'the start cell of your filter column
Set CurrentCell = StartCell


Dim i As Integer
i = 0
Do While CurrentCell.Value <> ""
    If CurrentCell.Value = 0 Then
        CurrentCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    i = i + 1
    Set CurrentCell = StartCell.Offset(i, 0)
Loop
```

Comment: The reason I want to use a filter is because when you manually hide rows it can take a few seconds, while filtering works in milliseconds.

Comment: Have you tried that with `Application.ScreenUpdating = false` before the code and `Application.ScreendUpdating = true` after the code?

Comment: The following is, hopefully, interesting, but not directly related to the question. If we click into a cell of one of the rows that contain ALL zeroes, press Ctrl-A to select the table, then Ctrl-G (GoTo), click Special.. and select **Column Differences**, this will select all the data that DO NOT contain the zero-rows. Then we can Ctrl-C (Copy) and Paste into a single cell below the table, to copy all the rows *except* those that are entirely zeroes. Excel is cool!